# Substituting X-axis ticks and text with percentile rank in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, axis-labels, ticker

I am currently trying to reproduce the following graph:
[Plot to be replicated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XXLe.png)

What I am struggling with is **substituting the x-axis ticks and text to be the percentile rank rather than the country ISO (essentially replicating the x-axis in the "Plot to be replicated")**.

I am currently at the stage in this image: [Attempted Replication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHU0p.png)

I am using the following code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = Cup, ymin = Cdo)) + 
  labs(x = "Country ISO",
       y = "Transparency Rating",
       title = "Transparency Index with CI") + 
  theme_light() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank() ,
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line( size=.05, color="grey") 
  )
```

I tried to use the options with various inputs but I can seem to make it work:

```
  theme(axis.ticks.x = ,
        axis.text.x =) 
  )
```

Some data useful for your replication:

```
x<-c("AFG","ALB","ITA",
     "IND","AGO","ARE",
     "ATG","BEN","BFA",
     "BGD","BGR","BHR",
     "BHS","BIH","BRB", 
     "BRN","BTN","BWA",
     "CAF","CAN")

y<-c(1:20)
Cup<-y+0.4
Cdo<-y-0.4

data<- data.frame(x,y,Cup,Cdo)
```

*Extra points for those who can also tell me how to add certain specific country names at the right point inside of the plot like in the "Plot to be replicated".*

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Create a new variable in your data frame called `rank` which is `seq(nrow(data))/nrow(data)` and use that (assuming `x` appears in the correct order in your data frame)

Comment: Hi Allan and thank you for your input. Where should I include this new rank variable in the ggplot code?

Comment: Create the variable in the data frame before the ggplot call.

Comment: Thank you again for the clarification. I still have not managed to implement it. I of course managed to create the variable but don't understand in which option of ggplot I should insert it. Could you please elaborate it further in a full written answer please?

Comment: You have to map the `rank` column suggested by Allan on `x`, i.e. `ggplot(..., aes(x = rank, ...))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Includes selective country labelling:

```r
library(tidyverse)

x <- c(
  "AFG", "ALB", "ITA",
  "IND", "AGO", "ARE",
  "ATG", "BEN", "BFA",
  "BGD", "BGR", "BHR",
  "BHS", "BIH", "BRB",
  "BRN", "BTN", "BWA",
  "CAF", "CAN"
)

y <- c(1:20)
Cup <- y + 0.4
Cdo <- y - 0.4

data <- data.frame(x, y, Cup, Cdo) |>
  mutate(rank = percent_rank(y))

labels <- data |>
  filter(x %in% c("ITA", "BGR", "CAN")) # select countries to label

data |>
  ggplot(aes(rank, y)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = x), data = labels, nudge_y = -2, angle = -90) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = Cup, ymin = Cdo)) +
  labs(
    x = "Pct Rank of Country ISO",
    y = "Transparency Rating",
    title = "Transparency Index with CI"
  ) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(size = .05, color = "grey")
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>